# How do I use nemo's file extract actions to extract to a specific folder?

Tags: 22.04, configuration, nemo

I have Ubuntu 22.04 and installed `nemo` as file manager and also `nemo-fileroller` 5.2.0-2. In /usr/share/nemo/actions you can define extra actions. I have found two different actions for "extract to", and both seem to be working, but I want to set the "extract to" to a special folder `/media/hd1/extracted`. I tried adding the path but it is not working, appreciate any help.

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Extract here NoSub
Comment=Extract here without creating a subfolder
Exec=bash -c 'file-roller --extract-to="$(dirname %F)" %F'
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
Selection=s
Extensions=zip;7z;ar;cbz;cpio;exe;iso;jar;tar;tar;7z;tar.Z;tar.bz2;tar.gz;tar.lz;tar.lzma;tar.xz;
```

and

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Extract to...
Comment=Extract to...
Exec=file-roller -f %F
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
#Stock-Id=gtk-cdrom
Selection=any
Extensions=zip;7z;ar;cbz;cpio;exe;iso;jar;tar;tar;7z;tar.Z;tar.bz2;tar.gz;tar.lz;tar.lzma;tar.xz;apk;
Quote=double
```

Comment: Please only post one question per Question. I have deleted the second question, but you can see in in the [edit history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1509068/revisions). You can copy and post that as a new question. Next, please [edit] and explain what you need a bit more clearly. What works? What doesn't work? And what are the codes you are showing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by the info in this site: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E37839/file-roller-1.html
My code is this (i do not know why %F has to be there, but without it the action does not work),

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Name=Extract to extracted
Comment=Extract to extracted
Exec=file-roller --extract-to=/media/hd1/extracted -f %F
Icon-Name=gnome-mime-application-x-compress
#Stock-Id=gtk-cdrom
Selection=s
Extensions=zip;7z;ar;cbz;cpio;exe;iso;jar;tar;tar;7z;tar.Z;tar.bz2;tar.gz;tar.lz;tar.lzma;tar.xz;apk;rar;r00;r01;
Quote=double
```